# ADFS return logout response with status code "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, saml-2.0, adfs

I am sending saml 2.0 logout request to ADFS and getting logout response with status code: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester".

I have checked Name ID value and it is equal to the name ID on Assertion.
I don't see any error on ADFS logs.

This is my Logout request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" Destination="https://IDP_adfs.xxx.com/adfs/ls/" ID="id007471cfceb449239be1a6a48d28ae89" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T15:30:56.3978094Z">
<saml:Issuer>https://SP.xxx.com</saml:Issuer>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
  <Reference URI="#id007471cfceb449239be1a6a48d28ae89">
    <Transforms>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>GsF...t/uwM=</DigestValue>
  </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>qY5RIT/eT9Tgkg7dj...IPn/2STu7iepIQ==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>MIIC5jCCAc...qAdOYsuKUgO9WNers=</X509Certificate>
  </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
<saml:NameID Format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN">user@xxx.com</saml:NameID>
<samlp:SessionIndex>_48b8991b-d3c4-4f8a-9c8b-a86e0a718c95</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

This is my Logout Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:LogoutResponse xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_79573c99-c8d3-4ea3-8b53-e15551128318" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T15:31:02.954Z" Destination="https://SP.xxx.com/Account/logout/" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="id007471cfceb449239be1a6a48d28ae89">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://IDP_Adfs.xxx.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
 <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
  <ds:Reference URI="#_79573c99-c8d3-4ea3-8b53-e15551128318">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>B/badvPpTrEuKZsqOvBQM54CIJ8=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>cWIEl5wY3...lIiQDltacRcjxyw==</ds:SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC2jCCAcKgAwIBA...LmlI6oFWC3Lw=</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
<samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester"/>
</samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

This is my saml response with the assertion:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_8b594b16-6505-4da6-9f4c-0d0d301bedb1" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T14:25:40.241Z" Destination="https://SP.xxx.com/" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_e32452c1-8651-49cc-b17b-87b45b9b4a52">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://IDP_Adfs.xxx.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
<samlp:Status>
<samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
</samlp:Status>
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_d6df6a72-99de-4935-8153-0db0d6f4b3f6" IssueInstant="2015-01-05T14:25:40.241Z" Version="2.0">
<Issuer>http://IDP_Adfs.xxx.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#_d6df6a72-99de-4935-8153-0db0d6f4b3f6">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>LUFxx...MY8=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>svLLi2ooLayZCvYCrZlDnLJAt2K7SzUcNSPS7m1Qlb1UUXZWoznd5gqusXRRrGazx6AVdnpcLgI6LVZ7xirOUBGpFxNZO7q/0zkyvzY7/lwhO4RTqtTHL2QlJTwapalWXZ9FCw0kTbmLgwgZaaqRUee5hE1kpDrIpusJXU9L9Abc/UBLZhAcstTaXDVUvCF/FH2dz2Kv9P07pV5Kcy0RvQWeJ5IkDZHefDYNsm+9Y+2V3kuPC4Ry54/7cxWc2DvDcYaKxht88/J2MA2kOqzF60Ty2Ka1hy1GpCviVO8X+SfWtgOpGcjj0NxJGSwqIcgF5PGXYfgR5sLF66xaY1t+9w==</ds:SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC2jCCAcKgA...lI6oFWC3Lw=</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<Subject>
  <NameID Format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN">user@xxx.com</NameID>
  <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_e32452c1-8651-49cc-b17b-87b45b9b4a52" NotOnOrAfter="2015-01-05T14:30:40.241Z" Recipient="https://SP.xxx.com/"/>
  </SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
<Conditions NotBefore="2015-01-05T14:25:40.241Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-01-05T15:25:40.241Z">
  <AudienceRestriction>
    <Audience>https://SP.xxx.com</Audience>
  </AudienceRestriction>
</Conditions>
<AttributeStatement>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
    <AttributeValue>user@xxx.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
    <AttributeValue>user@xxx.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName">
    <AttributeValue>User User</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
<AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-01-05T14:25:40.225Z" SessionIndex="_d6df6a72-99de-4935-8153-0db0d6f4b3f6">
  <AuthnContext>
    <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
  </AuthnContext>
</AuthnStatement>
</Assertion>
 </samlp:Response>
```

I am using HTTP-POST binding to send the logout request and get the logout response.
There is a problem with my logout request according to "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" status code, but unfortunately i don't find it.

Comment: turn up ADFS 2.0 debugging and find out more about the error on the ADFS side as described here: http://www.messageops.com/office-365-tech-tips/support/tech-tip-of-the-week-enable-adfs-tracing-logs-in-event-viewer/

Answer (score 5):

`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester` means that ADFS didn't "like" the request and blames the source of the request. As Hans Z points out there should be something in the ADFS log and trace files. If there are no messages then do check your ADFS patch and hotfix levels.

Now the problem in the above message. For signout there must be two correct identifications: NameID and SessionIndex. Although you seem to have edited the XML, which makes anything I write speculative.... The problem could be the SessionIndex.

In the assertion: `AuthnStatement@SessionIndex="_d6df6a72-99de-4935-8153-0db0d6f4b3f6"` In the LogoutRequest-SessionIndex has value `_48b8991b-d3c4-4f8a-9c8b-a86e0a718c95`

I have not looked at other possible errors, because you seem to have edited the XML. The validating parser would refuse it for that reason and thus miss other possible problems.

Comment: As you suggested. 'For signout there must be two correct identifications: NameID and SessionIndex'. Session ID should be same as we received in SAMLResponse. could you please clarify that what should NameID contain in logout request?